# Send response data from a parent component to a modal component, edit and update database, vue3

Tags: vue.js

Consider these two components in `vue3.js`

**PostsComponent.vue**

```
<template>
 <table>
   <template v-for="attributes in posts">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ attributes.attributes.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ attributes.attributes.post_content }}</td>
        <button type="button" class="btn" @click="editPost(attributes.id)">edit</button>
    </tr>
  </template>
 </table>

  <ModalComponent v-show="isModalVisible" @close="closeModal" />
 ...
</template>     

<script>
import ModalComponent from './ModalComponent.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        ModalComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            info: null,
            message: null,
            postTitle: "",
            postContent: "",
            postStatus: "",
            postCreatedAt: "",
            isModalVisible: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showModal() {
            this.isModalVisible = true;
        },

        closeModal() {
            this.isModalVisible = false;
        },

        fetchData(id) {
          
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/' + id, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('apiToken')
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
            });

        },

        editPost(id) {
            this.isModalVisible = true;

            let response = this.fetchData(id);

            console.log(response); // works a charm
            
           // now send response data to ModalComponent from here, ready for editing?

        },

        deletePost(value) {
            console.log('delete post clicked', value);
        }
    },
    
    mounted() {
       // successfully got the response, loading the page with an array of posts
    }
}
</script>
```

**ModalComponent**

```
<template>
    <transition name="modal-fade">
        <div class="modal-backdrop">
            <div class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-describedby="modalDescription">
                <header class="modal-header" id="modalTitle">
                    <slot name="header">
                        This is the default title! 
                    </slot>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" @click="close" aria-label="Close modal">
                        x
                    </button>
                </header>
                <section class="modal-body" id="modalDescription">
                    <slot name="body">
                        This is the default body!
                    </slot>
                </section>
                <footer class="modal-footer">
                    <slot name="footer">
                        This is the default footer!
                    </slot>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-green" @click="close" aria-label="Close modal">
                        Close Modal
                    </button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ModalComponent',
    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit('close');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

The `ModalComponent` has `<slots>` defined, I'm told these are entirely reusable. I'm totally new to vue.js.

How do I pass data from the `PostsComponent.vue` to my `ModalComponent.vue` via the `editPost(id)` event handler once I've successfully grabbed all my response data?

My goal is to edit the content within the modal and then make another `PUT` request to an API backend to update the database with the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use props for passing data from parent to children https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

**PostComponents.vue**

```js
<template>
  // bind the child props with your data that will be passed
  <ModalComponent v-show="isModalVisible" @close="closeModal" :dataFromParent='dataFromApi' />
</template>     


data() {
    return {
       // define data that will be passed to children
       dataFromApi: '',
   }
},
```

**ModalComponents**

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    // define name and type of the props
    dataFromParent: Object,
  }
};

// you can access the props object
console.log(props.dataFromParent)
</script>
```

after the props already setup, you need to insert some data to the data that will be passed to children, so when the `editPost` function already done fetching data, insert that response data to the variable that will be passed to children